# mongodb update multiple records from command line

Tags: mongodb

i have this code

```
var new_styles = ["XEP02" ,"XEP65" ,"XEPB01" ,"XEPB03" ,"XN06" ,"XN14" ,"XN73"];

for( var i = 0; i < new_styles.length; i++ ) {
    var style_name = [i];
    var full_length = "/assets/full_length/low_res/" + style_name + ".jpg";
    var cropped =  "/assets/cropped/low_res/" + style_name + ".jpg";
    db.styles.update({"_id": style_name},  {"$push" : {"images.full_lenght": full_length, "images.cropped": cropped }});
}
```

when i run it on the mongo console, it does not seem to work, where as

```
db.styles.update({"_id": "XEP02"},  {"$push" : {"images.full_lenght": "/assets/full_length/low_res/XEP02.jpg", "images.cropped": "/assets/cropped/low_res/XEP02.jpg"}});
```

works

what am i missing?

Comment: `style_name = [i]` what are you trying to do with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a bug in your for loop, it currently queries for `"_id":0`,`"_id":1`,etc. You need to change `var style_name = [i]` to this:

```
 var style_name = new_styles[i];
```